# how to disable a table and iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript

`iFrame.document.getElementById('Formname').disabled = true;`
This is not working with Netscape browsers(FF,Chrome and Safari).
Can some please help ?

or
How to disable entire whenpage when a button is clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only interactive elements, such as form fields and buttons can be disabled.

Comment: Then how can make the table elements looks like disabled? I mean to display in grey color.

Comment: What you do is make a DIV that is translucent and use absolute positioning to place it over the table.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IE applies the disabled property recursively; nice, I didn't know that. For other browsers, try something like this:

```
   var formInputs = iFrame.document.getElementById('Formname').getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
   for (var input in formInputs) {
      input.disabled = true;
   }
```

This code isn't tested and won't disable any TEXTAREAs in the form, adding them is left as an exercise.